# how to manage raw pointers in cpp without shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, c, shared-ptr

If I use cpp without `shared_ptr`, how to manage the instance's life time and one-to-mutiple ownership? Is there any convention can be followed?
For example, DirectX has `D3DDevice*`, `D3DDeviceContext*` everywhere and mesh can be owned by sereval objects.

Put it in to an manager to hold its life time and alway pass it by ref, can this be a good solution?

And how does C manage raw pointer and ownership in a project?

Any reply will be appreciated.

Comment: The language won´t do anything, *you* do it. By thinking what can be deleted when and why.

Comment: Define your own RAII structure.

Comment: I sense an XY problem. Why in particular do you dont want to use shared_ptr ?

Comment: In C nothing is provided for pointer safety, but the problem does not even come up since there are no exceptions or destructors. If you do need to abandon code using `longjmp` or some such, it is entirely up to you to avoid memory leaks, which is a daunting task. An example of some sort of handling is in the `bison` parser generator for the case a parse must be abandoned due to a syntax error.

Comment: http://molecularmusings.wordpress.com/2013/05/02/adventures-in-data-oriented-design-part-3a-ownership/  This may tell part of why no shard_ptr and how to manage the object has many instances, and for object has only one or two instance like d3ddevice*, RAII may be the solution.

Comment: Another reason for not to use shared_ptr is that if you work with other code, you need pass a pointer to other interfaces, then ref count may not help you to keep the instance automatically.

Answer (score 1):

In short an [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) maintains **reference counting** ownership of its contained pointer in cooperation with all copies of it. This means that several `std::shared_ptr` objects may own the same object through a pointer. The mentioned object will be destroyed when the last remaining `std::shared_ptr` owning it is destroyed or assigned another pointer.

You can implement the same functionality using [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_acquisition_is_initialization) as follows:

```
template<typename T> class MySharedPtr {
public:
    MySharedPtr() : ref_count(new int(1)), obj_ptr(0) {
    }
    MySharedPtr(T* new_ptr) : ref_count(new int(1)), obj_ptr(new_ptr) {
    }
    MySharedPtr(const MySharedPtr<T>& other) :
            ref_count(other.ref_count), obj_ptr(other.obj_ptr) {
        (*ref_count)++;
    }
    ~MySharedPtr() {
        if(--(*ref_count) == 0) {
            delete ref_count;
            delete obj_ptr;
        }
    }
    MySharedPtr<T>& operator=(const MySharedPtr<T>& other) {
        if(this != &other) {
            if(--(*ref_count) == 0) {
                delete ref_count;
                delete obj_ptr;
            }

            ref_count = other.ref_count;
            obj_ptr = other.obj_ptr;
            (*ref_count)++;
        }
        return *this;
    }
    T& operator*() { return *obj_ptr; }
    T* operator->() { return obj_ptr; }

private:
    int* ref_count;
    T* obj_ptr;
};
```

In [c](/questions/tagged/c) the story is the same, you have to maintain the reference count and deallocate the managed space when the reference count become zero. An example with an [opaque pointer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer) can be the following:

**example.h**

```
#ifndef EXAMPLE_H
#define EXAMPLE_H

struct MyType;

struct MyType* new_MyType();
struct MyType* ref_MyType(struct MyType*);
struct MyType* unref_MyType(struct MyType*);

float MyType_getData(struct MyType*);

#endif /* EXAMPLE_H */
```

**example.c**

```
#include "example.h"
#include <stdlib.h>

struct MyType {
    int ref_count;
    float some_data;
};

struct MyType* new_MyType() {
    struct MyType* obj_ptr = (struct MyType*)malloc(sizeof(struct MyType));
    obj_ptr->some_data = 0.0f;
    obj_ptr->ref_count = 1;
}
struct MyType* ref_MyType(struct MyType* obj_ptr) {
    if(obj_ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;
    obj_ptr->ref_count++;
    return obj_ptr;
}
struct MyType* unref_MyType(struct MyType* obj_ptr) {
    if(obj_ptr == NULL)
        return NULL;

    if(--(obj_ptr->ref_count) == 0) {
        free(obj_ptr);
        return NULL;
    }
    return obj_ptr;
}

float MyType_getData(struct MyType* obj_ptr) {
    return (obj_ptr != NULL ? obj_ptr->some_data : 0.0f);
}
```